# Web Scraping: How to extract href from a HTML piece?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a real estate web scraping script and I am stuck on how to get the `href` from this piece of HTML code with BeautifulSoup from [this](https://www.notar.se/kopa-bostad?assignmentStatus=Kommande&assignmentStatus=Till%20salu&numberOfRoomsMin&numberOfRoomsMax&livingSpaceAreaMax) site

HTML of the Targeted Element:

```
<a data-v-0354ca3a="" href="/kopa-bostad/objekt/4MDBKG9311MD8M25" class="card d-flex flex-column mb-8 v-card v-card--link v-sheet theme--light" tabindex="0" style="width: 100%;">
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup treats each HTML tag as dictionary, you can get the `href` of the `<a>` tag like this,

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a data-v-0354ca3a="" href="/kopa-bostad/objekt/4MDBKG9311MD8M25" class="card d-flex flex-column mb-8 v-card v-card--link v-sheet theme--light" tabindex="0" style="width: 100%;">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(i['href'])
```

Outputs:

```
/kopa-bostad/objekt/4MDBKG9311MD8M25
```

And here, `i` in the for loop is the `variable_name_that_has_the_tag_element`

If you want to get only the HTML that you mentioned in the question from a full HTML Page Source, use `class_` parameter in the `find_all` method, or use a dictionary to mention the HTML tag's classname, like

```py
for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='card d-flex flex-column mb-8 v-card v-card--link v-sheet theme--light'):
    print(i['href'])
```

Or

```py
for i in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'card d-flex flex-column mb-8 v-card v-card--link v-sheet theme--light'}):
  print(i['href'])
```

Both the code still outputs,

```
/kopa-bostad/objekt/4MDBKG9311MD8M25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<a data-v-0354ca3a="" href="/kopa-bostad/objekt/4MDBKG9311MD8M25" class="card d-flex flex-column mb-8 v-card v-card--link v-sheet theme--light" tabindex="0" style="width: 100%;">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.a['href']
```

Output:

```
'/kopa-bostad/objekt/4MDBKG9311MD8M25'
```

Comment: Thank you! It works great for this one, but how to I use some command to get the variable html automatically from the full html code?

Comment: For that, I need to see the HTML for the XPath and other things. Can you please share the HTML file or URL with me.?